# Show big icons in notification center

Tags: ios

Is it possible for third party apps to show big icons and interactive content in notification center? Something like weather or stocks app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Store apps? Nope. Jailbreak? Maybe.

Comment: Asking your question again won't change the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apple will reject any apps that use the notification centre for anything but notifications.

Comment: Come to think of it, apple ain't too keen on having anyone commandeer Notification Center at all.